# Unwanted automatically started tmpfs and lib/systemd/systemd --user process for not logged in user

Tags: debian, systemd, pam, tmpfs

Debian 11 Bullseye pc, systemd, no display manager, `startx` is used to start X, multiple users.

When I login with a user, let's say auser-UID 1000, I see this on process list:

```
USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY     STAT START   TIME COMMAND
foo      550  0.0  0.1  15280  8928 ?       Ss   16:18   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
foo      554  0.0  0.0 166520  2732 ?       S    16:18   0:00 (sd-pam)
auser    657  0.0  0.1  15280  8928 ?       Ss   16:18   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
auser    658  0.0  0.0 166520  2732 ?       S    16:18   0:00 (sd-pam)
```

Apparently they are related to these mounts (foo-UID 1001):
cropped `mount` command result:

```
tmpfs on /run/user/1001 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=791080k,nr_inodes=197770,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1001)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=791080k,nr_inodes=197770,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

That's prior to starting X, very few processes, nothing in my knowledge is started automatically by `foo` which is not logged in.

How can I locate what starts these 2 `foo` processes? It happens automatically at boot, there is an entry in journal:

```
systemd[542]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user foo(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
```

There are also other local users on the system, but no tmpfs is started automatically for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
sudo loginctl disable-linger foo
```

Apparently searching for something else I had enabled linger on that user, which does exactly this, starts systemd user instance on boot instead of log in.